# Controlling Master Template in Blade

Tags: laravel-blade, laravel-5.1

I am very new to Laravel and I have a question. Say that I have a master template that has the header and the sidebar of the site and the content is filed with child templates. And say that I have a private messages link in a dropdown menu in the header. This link should always show the number of new messages no matter which route the user is currently at. How to achieve this? Writing a method that populates the nav-bar and calling it in every controller doesn't seem elegant.

Answer (score 1):

You might look at [Blade Service Injection](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#service-injection).

In your master template, you could add the following:

`@inject('messages', 'App\Services\PrivateMessageService')`

Then, in the template section, you could pull the correct number from that service:

`New Messages: {{ $messages->unreadCount() }}`

Comment: Thanks I will try it!